# Issue with an API calls Windows Server

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-7, windows-server-2008, amazon-web-services

I wrote a web app that makes API calls to a web service. This works fine on the development server and when I run the app on my Windows 7 machine. I can't get this to run on Windows Server 2008. I have played with the firewall and still nothing is working. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I added the domain to trusted sites(through IE) and restarted IIS.

Comment: Can you get to the webservice url from a browser on your Windows 2008 server?

Comment: @David it seems that I can navigate to the domain fine(and the actual URL as much well as I can in Win7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was in issue with the time on the host being 12 hours behind the client(ie AM went it was PM). I changed this and it seemed to work fine. This is quite odd and I am going to look into further.